# Filtering DbgPrint in WinDBG?

Tags: filtering, windbg

Finally found out how to make DbgPrint to really print in Win Vista/7 with:

```
ed nt!Kd_DEFAULT_Mask 0xffffffff
```

The problem is that there is some other drivers talking to the command prompt ni WinDbg. Is there a way to filter so only DbgPrint from my .sys file will reach the command prompt in WinDbg?

I know about DbgPrintEx but I'm not so into migrating my old driver with tons of DbgPrint to DbgPrintEx if there is an easier way for simple filtering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the .ofilter command? This filters at the host so it's not as fast as using DbgPrintEx, but it works in a pinch.

-scott